# Running BCP simultaneously in cloud SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows, sqlcmd

We recently migrated all processing from on premises SQL Server 2008 to Cloud SQL Server 2016. We often uses BCP commands to load sources (daily text files into tables) and final output (from table to text files).

Lately we are often facing issue when we execute 2 or more BCP commands simultaneously, we are getting an error

> The process can not access the file because it is used by another process

Most BCP commands pulls data from different folder and extracts to different folders. Unfortunately we have never face that issue, when we executed those against on-premise SQL Server 2008.

Please let us know how can we enable parallel execution for `xp_cmdshell bcp` script in SQL Server.

You can also see below sample of BCP command

```
declare @bcp_command varchar(2000)

set @bcp_command = bcp db_name.dbo.table_sale out F:\drive\outbound\sale.txt -c -t"~" -S(OCI Server) -Uusername -r"\n" -Ppassword

exec xp_cmdshell @bcpcommand
```